# Почему не работают два where одновременно при выборке данных по дате в указанном диапазоне? (eloquent+carbon)

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, carbon

В контроллере для записи данных в БД в столбец **reportdate** использую:

```
'reportdate' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request -> reportdate),
...
```

На данный момент столбец **reportdate** содержит:

```
2018-08-01
2018-07-12
2018-08-16
2018-08-31
2018-09-21
```

В модели добавил строку:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at','reportdate'];
```

При выводе данных из БД использую код:

```
getMonthStatistic(Carbon::now());
...
public static function getMonthStatistic($date){

    $report = DayReport::with('elementary')
        //->where("reportdate", ">=", $date->startOfMonth())
        //->where("reportdate", "<=", $date->endOfMonth())
        ->where("username", "=", Auth::user()->name)->first();
    //dd($report);
    dd($date->startOfMonth(), $report->reportdate);
```

Если **where** закомментированы, то я получаю все записи из бд для текущего пользователя (все 5 штук), вот даты, которые я вывожу через **dd()** - см.код выше:

```
Carbon @1533081600 {#318 ▼
date: 2018-08-01 00:00:00.042117 UTC (+00:00)
}
Carbon @1533151002 {#365 ▼
date: 2018-08-01 19:16:42.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Но если раскомментировать две строки **where**, то получаю пустой результат. Как мне сравнить текущую дату с датами в таблице?

Заметил странную особенность, что если раскомментировать только одну из двух строк:

```
        //->where("reportdate", ">=", $date->startOfMonth())
        //->where("reportdate", "<=", $date->endOfMonth())
```

то в обоих случая я получаю по 4 из 5 записей из БД, т.е. все работает, т.к. выпадает либо дата 2018-07-12, либо дата 2018-09-21. Но почему не работают два where одновременно?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался что здесь было не так. Значения $date->startOfMonth() и $date->endOfMonth() получаются идентичны из-за особенностей работы Carbon. Поэтому делаю через метод copy():

```
$report = DayReport::with('elementary')
    ->where("reportdate", ">=", $date->startOfMonth())
    ->where("reportdate", "<=", $date->copy()->endOfMonth())
    ->where("username", "=", Auth::user()->name)->first();
```